# Audio not playing back after publishing webisite on school server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, server

I am a 3rd year IT(Software Dev) student and im currently developing my final year project. The whole success of my system is based on how well the system's audibility interacts with the user (3-10 years) as they are not yet able to read.

I am developing in MVC 5, i use a webservice method to retrieve my audio files from the database and JQuery to play it on my views:

```
public void PlayAudio(int id)
    {


        using (The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_FactoryDBContext())
        {
            if (db.Words.FirstOrDefault(word => word.wordID == id).engAudio != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = db.Words.FirstOrDefault(word => word.wordID == id).engAudio;

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                System.Media.SoundPlayer myPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ms);
                myPlayer.Play();
            }
        }



    }
```

JQuery:

```
function PlayAudio() {
                var id = $("[id$=hiddenWord_id]").val();
                $.ajax({

                    url: "../../WebService.asmx/PlayAudio",
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
            };
```

Now the above code has not at all given me trouble whilst running the system on my local machine. However I published my website&database onto the school server and none of the audio on the website plays back. There is no error when i try to play the audio and everything else seems to be fine. I do not know if it is a coding problem or if the problem is on the server.

Can anyone please advise me what steps should i take in trying to fix this. 
Thank you.

Comment: None of your Javascript code tries to play audio at all. You need to create an `<audio>` HTML element with its source set to the file's URL or a "data" URL with the base64-encoded data.

Comment: How do you mean @AndréB. ? This code does work running locally. What is the difference.

Comment: It runs locally because what actually plays the audio is your C# code through the `System.Media.SoundPlayer` object and not your browser, but if you want everyone else to be able to hear the sound with their browser you'll need to make it play using the method I described previously.

Comment: Dont save audio in database, better is save in disk